# HttpContext.Items vs Scoped Service

Tags: asp.net-core

Which is the better way to carry request data(Is there any difference between two way)?

For example:

Option 1(`Scoped Service`):

```
//Scoped Service(this may be interface)
public class SampleScopedService
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

//Register service
services.AddScoped<SampleScopedService>();

//Set and Get Data
public class SampleUsage
{
    private readonly SampleScopedService _sampleScopedService;
    public SampleUsage(SampleScopedService sampleScopedService)
    {
        _sampleScopedService = sampleScopedService;
        // _sampleScopedService.Data = "Sample";
        // _sampleScopedService.Data 
    }
}
```

Option 2(`HttpContext.Items`)

```
//Scoped Service
public class SampleScopedService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public SampleScopedService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
    public string GetData()
    {
        return (string)_accessor.HttpContext.Items["Data"];
    }
}

//Register service
services.AddScoped<SampleScopedService>();

//Set Data
HttpContext.Items[“Data”] = ”Sample”;

//Get Data
public class SampleUsage
{
    private readonly SampleScopedService _sampleScopedService;
    public SampleUsage(SampleScopedService sampleScopedService)
    {
        _sampleScopedService = sampleScopedService;
        //_sampleScopedService.GetData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#recommendations):

> Avoid storing data and configuration directly in DI. For example, a
>   user’s shopping cart shouldn’t typically be added to the services
>   container. Configuration should use the Options Model. Similarly,
>   avoid “data holder” objects that only exist to allow access to some
>   other object. It’s better to request the actual item needed via DI, if
>   possible.

Since **Options 1** is example of  “data holder”, as far as possible we should avoid it.

Furthermore, **Options 1** may cause [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) if you don't pay attention.

So using **Option 2** with singleton lifetime is better way than using **Option 1**.

Comment: I think "Avoid storing data and configuration directly in DI" is against `services.AddScoped<DataHolder>(sp => new DataHolder { Value = "value" })`

What about "It's better to request the actual item needed via DI, if possible" - it is like `services.AddScoped<Data>(sp => sp.GetService<DataGetter>().GetData())`.

In my practice I often need to set some value, retrieved from db/queue-message, to be used in some services later throughout request processing. For such case I see nothing bad to use Option 1 (also `HttpContext.Items` can hold only strings, i.e. additional serialization need).

Comment: @smg I haven't really messed with HttpContext.Items much but a quick look at the source on github shows its just a HashTable behind the scenes. Both the key and the value are just object, technically speaking it seems like you should be able to store instances of objects in there. Whether or not that is good practice is another matter entirely.